# How to plot the shortest distance between two lines passing through an arbitrary point using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, distance, line-drawing

I have a picture with lines drawn on it.

And, I want to draw a straight line with the shortest distance between two lines passing through an arbitrary point.
with **Python OpenCV**

This is a code that can extract green from the original image and draw dots with mouse from the thinned image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
def on_mouse(event, x,y,flags,param):
   if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
      cv2.line(img,(x,y),(x,y),(255,0,0),2)
      cv2.imshow('thinned',thinned)

def colorPickandThinning(img):
   height, width = img.shape[:2] 

   img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
 
   lower_green = (40,60,0) 
   upper_green = (80, 255, 255) 
   img_mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_green, upper_green)

   img[:, :, 0] = 0
   img[:, :, 2] = 0
   img[:, :, 1] = img_mask
   img_temp = img

   # filtering image nosiecancel
   noisecancel = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img_temp,None,49,57,7,21)
   cv2.imshow('noise',noisecancel)

   #thinning
   thinned = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(cv2.cvtColor(noisecancel,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY))

   return thinned

img = cv2.imread('test_img.jpg')
thinned = colorPickandThinning(img)
cv2.imshow('thinned',thinned)
cv2.setMouseCallback('thinned',on_mouse,thinned)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is a result picture and I drew a dot with the mouse.

[image]

I want to draw like this picture.

[image]

Comment: At first, you can detect the lines horizontally, and then you can find the shortest one by looking at the euclidean distances of the coordinates of these 3 lines in X, Y.

Comment: Intersect a perpendicular from the point to each curve. Extend each perpendicular in the other direction to intersect with the other curve. Take the line between the two curves that is the shortest of the two.

Comment: I know what you're talking about. But, I'd like to know of an easier open source or library to get the answer.